# Unable to render create-react-app boilerplate views from Flask backend

Tags: python, reactjs, flask, create-react-app

I'm having a hard time integrating [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app) single page application to my flask backend. I want to be able to make a fetch/axios call from my front end like so: axios.get('/getResults') and fetch('/getResults'). Some things I have tried but not limited to is specifying the Flask port as 3000 which is the same used by create-react-app. Also, used the proxy configuration feature on the "package.json" file of create-react-app but to no avail. I suspect my folder structure and Flask code implementation may likely be causing this. Below is my folder structure and "app.py" code. Any help I could get will be appreciated. I can provide additional information if necessary. Thanks

Project 
-build(contains static folder, index.html...Other meta files)
-node_modules
-public
-src
app.py
package.json
requirements.txt

app.py:

```
from flask import Flask, Response, request, jsonify, make_response, send_from_directory,render_template

app = Flask(__name__, static_path='/build/static/')
app.debug=True

@app.route('/')
def root():
    print('Inside root function')
    return app.send_static_file('index.html')

@app.route('/getResults', methods=["GET"])
def results():
    print('Inside getResults path')
    return app.send_static_file('index.html')

@app.route('/postData', methods=["POST"])
def data_results():
    print('Inside postData path')
    data = request.get_json
    return jsonify(data)

@app.route('/<path:path>')
def send_js(path):
    print("inside send_js fxn")
    return send_from_directory('./build/static',path)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("inside main host call")
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=3000)
```

Errors I get when I run "python app.py" are:

On the terminal: Inside root function
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Jun/2017 09:42:24] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 -

On the browser:Not Found - The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

Comment: how are you running create-react-app, with `npm start` ?

Comment: I run it with yarn start and yarn build so I can use the static files for the flask backend

Comment: @dlvr did you look at my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/45245402/140837

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having the exact same issue and I was able to solve it by appeasing Flask with symlinks.

Keep the templates and static directory paths at their defaults and in the directory with your Flask main file, add these symlinks

```
ln -s build/ templates
ln -s build/static static
```

In case you were curious, this was my specific problem, which just involved a few more nested directories but was in essence the same:

[Running NPM Build from Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45242537/running-npm-build-from-flask)

You can then use Nurzhan's root configuration:

```
@app.route('/')
def root():
    print('Inside root function')
    return render_template('index.html')
```

But you only require your app declaration to be: `app = Flask(__name__)`

The only thing that doesn't work for me is the favicon, and I will update this answer once I figure that out.

Comment: How to you use hot reloading with that configuration?

Comment: @amirouche I'm actually not sure to be quite honest. If you have a solution to using hot reloading and API with a single origin than I would love to hear it, since I need that with my app too. I'm not using Ajax however, only React with axios.

Comment: Did you look at my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/45245402/140837 also I have a project using it at https://github.com/amirouche/socialite

Comment: @amirouche Is your site a production build? According to this post, the `proxy` field will only resolve in development mode with `npm start`. Production builds will throw a CORS error. https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#proxying-api-requests-in-development

Comment: No, it's not a production build.

Comment: Sorry that I'm revisiting this now guys. Combination of @Cole and @amirouche recommendations resolved this. I included the proxy variable on my package.json file and used the symlinks command.

here's how my app.py file now looks:

`app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('index.html')`

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

In development mode, you need to configure your create-react-app `package.json` to forward "ajax" request to the flask server.

Here is what my `package.json` looks like:

```
{
  "name": "socialite",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "proxy": "http://localhost:8080",
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-scripts": "1.0.10"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.6.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

See the `proxy` field? That's where the magic happens, replace its value with the flask server address. That way, you can take advantage of CRA hot reloading feature. This is documented at in [create-react-app as "Proxying API Requests in Development"](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#proxying-api-requests-in-development)

Then do run your application, you go at `localhost:3000` or whatever port yarn opens for you. And when you do an *API* call in javascript over the rainbow to the server for instance: `fetch('/api/model/')` or something nodejs' server will forward to the flask app. I think the nodejs server does look at the content-type field of the ajax request to know whether it should forward the request to the backend server or not.

I recommend you prefix all your backend routes with something like `/api/v1/` or something so the nginx configuration is neat and easy to write.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a number of misunderstandings.

The `create-react-app` runs on its own server on port 3000 and if you try to run your flask app on the same port on the same machine it will complain that port 3000 is already in use. So from this we move to another question - the structure of your application.

Will it be a separate reactjs based client on the frontend and api based on flask in the backend which will be 2 separate applications communicating with each other over HTTP? In this case the frontend and backend will usually run on separate servers.

Or it will one flask application which will use reactjs in its template pages?

You can fix your current problem with not finding URL by changing to this in your code:

```
@app.route('/')
def root():
    print('Inside root function')
    return render_template('index.html')
```

And this:

```
template_dir = os.path.abspath('build/templates')
app = Flask(__name__, static_path='/build/static/',
            template_folder=template_dir)
```

Since your templates folder is in the `build` directory.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Nurzhan. Even when I change the port to 5000 and use the snippet you recommended above, it's still unsuccessful. Also, I moved some meta files and index.html into a templates folder in the build folder. Now my build folder is like this: 
-build
--static(contains: js,css and media)
--templates(contains: index.html, asset-manifest. json,manifest.json, service-worker.js, favicon.ico)

Comment: @dlvr What is the response? Is it still not found? It works for me. Probably you didn't do exactly as I wrote. Have decided what architecture will you be using for your app?

Comment: **These are the responses from the terminal:**

Inside root function
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Jun/2017 23:11:50] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
inside send_js fxn
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Jun/2017 23:11:50] "GET /static/css/main.9a0fe4f1.css HTTP/1.1" 404 -
inside send_js fxn
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Jun/2017 23:11:50] "GET /static/js/main.50dca1bb.js HTTP/1.1" 404 -

Comment: @dlvr What URL are you trying to access? It complains about he css and js files which cannot be found. Are they present in those locations?

Comment: **I did as you recommended:**

template_dir = os.path.abspath('build/templates')
app = Flask(__name__, static_path='/build/static/',
            template_folder=template_dir)
app.debug=True


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("inside main host call")
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)

Comment: @dlvr What urls are you using? The idea was to show how to render properly a template in flask if you moved you template and static directories to non-standard location.

Comment: I'm using http:localhost:5000 to acess the page. I may be missing something here. I'm thinking I could wire the frontend and the backend and can specify the flask backend server url on my front-end like so:  `axios.get('/getResults')` or `fetch('/getResults')`. Isn't it that possible?

Comment: @dlvr As far as I know you can. So you want a monolithic app and not to split the application into 2 apps - one is js client and another is flask backend?

Comment: Either a monolithic or non-monolithic. As long as they can both talk to each other.

Comment: @dlvr I don't see much information to help you. I am just guessing at the moment. Could you paste more info?

Comment: What additional information would you like? Sure I can provide you with as much information as possible. Are you ok with moving this discussion to a chat?

Comment: This is not how you configure CRA during developpement.